# how do tags get added to database using acts_as_taggable_on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

I've tried to follow the somewhat limited instructions and tutorials I've been able to find re: acts_as_taggable_on.

I've got it running, and have run the migrations on the database.

My model includes

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable
  acts_as_taggable_on :interests,:partners
```

Then in my form, I've added

```
 <%= semantic_form_for @task, :html=>{:multipart=>true} do |form| %>
 <%= form.text_field :interest_list %>
 <%= form.text_field :partner_list %>
```

I figured it would be too easy to just add the tags into the fields, but can't find any documentation on how this is supposed to be done.

Answer (score 0):

apparently the issue was

1) create your form fields as tagname_list

2) I forgot to add the tagname_list to attr_accessible, though I had tagnames there.

Comment: what did you change, I have done what you said...what do you mean create your form fields as tagname_list, isn't that what you already have?

Answer (score 0):

What that means is to follow the instructions on the [gem page](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on). Then to use acts_as_taggable_on :yoursomefield follow these conventions:

```
//add to model
attr_accessible :yourfieldname_list
acts_as_taggable_on :yourfieldname

//view
<%= f.text_field :yourfieldname_list %>
```